# How to know if a bot on my server is verified or not?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I would like to know if it is possible to know if a bot on my server is verified or not, with a command (using python), I do not find good information in forums.

[image]

```py
@bot.command
async def verify(ctx, bot_name):
  ???
  pass
```

or

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  ???
  pass
```

does anyone know if there is any way to know through a command or event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public flags within discord.py in order to figure this out. Below are two ways you could do this, both through a command and an event.

You can learn more about public flags in the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord#discord.PublicUserFlags).

Command Method:

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def is_verified(ctx, bot_member:discord.Member):
        is_verified_bot = bot_member.public_flags.verified_bot

        if is_verified_bot:
            print (bot_member, "is verified!")
        
        else:
            print (bot_member, "is not verified!")
```

Event Method:

```py
    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        is_verified_bot = member.public_flags.verified_bot

        if is_verified_bot:
            print (bot_member, "is verified!")
        
        else:
            print (bot_member, "is not verified!")
```

Note: In order to use the `on_member_join` event method, you will need to have Member intents enabled.

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I needed :b